# what is inductive class of algebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, computational-algebra

When I was studying the following lemma from an article , I faced to some notations I was not familiar with them, I would appreciate your  help  to find out them:

> Lemma:Let $X$ be an inductive class of
>   algebras over a field $K$. Suppose $X$ is closed under subalgebra and $L \in  X$.
>   Then there exists an algebra $H \in X$ containing $L$ such that its dimension is
>   at most $$ max \{ \aleph_{0} , dim (L), |k|\}$$.
>   What is the meaning of "inductive class" and "close under subalgebra"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order relation  in this class X is the existence of
monomorphisms, so $X$ is inductive ,  this means that any
monomorphism chain of algebra $ A_0\hookrightarrow
A_1\hookrightarrow\cdot \cdot \cdot \hookrightarrow A_n$ has a
limit in $X$ (that is inductive limit of this chain).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And what is the meaning of "close under subalgebra"?  For example, how can we show that the class of Leibniz algebras are inductive class ?

Comment: i think the objet of X is all leibniz algebra are module over the seame ring R, so the inductive limet exist and also the leibniz identity is satistfaid for this R-modul, to be closed i thik any algebra x  is incluse in maximal  algebra